# How to render data from database in twig using PHP slim

Tags: php, slim

Im trying to render data from my database into twig within an controller. Sorta like a mvc structure but without the model.

Right now it just renders

My todos

I'm surprised that the [slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/) doesn't contain this sort of instructions

Any suggestions, thanks in advance.

TodosController.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers;

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

class TodosController extends BaseController
{
    public function index($request, $response)
    {

    }


    public function getTodos($request, $response, $args)
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY task");
        $sth->execute();
        $todos = $sth->fetchAll();

        return $this->c->view->render($response, 'todos.twig', $todos);




    }
}
```

todos.twig

```
{% extends "templates/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>My Todos</h1>

<ul>
  {% for task in todos %}
        <li><span>{{ task.id}}</span> {{ task.task}}</li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you have in `$todos` when you var_dump it in `TodosController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your `todos` into array

```
$this->c->view->render($response, 'todos.twig', ['todos' => $todos]);
```

Comment: how did you know this  where can i see more documentation on this? because it worked. thank you